# npm install not installing nested dependency, but does install them when installing explicitly

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs, npm-install, ts-jest

I have a package (https://github.com/Voitanos/jest-preset-spfx) with the a few `dependencies`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "28.1.4",
  "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
  "jest-junit": "14.0.0",
  "ts-jest": "28.0.5"
}
```

The package includes a shrinkwrap file. The intention of this package is to install it in another project where it installs these specific version dependencies.

Now... when I install this package, there are no errors/warnings & it completes successfully, yetI see three inconsistent things happening that's confusing:

- two dependencies (identity-obj-proxy & jest-junit) are installed with the expected versions
- one dependency (@types/jest) was already present as an older version (by another dependency in the original project), but the version I'm specifying isn't installed
- one dependency (ts-jest) isn't installed at all

Looking at the verbose NPM install logs, I can see all the expected versions listed for all three types of behaviors above... 75% of them have only my version listed:

```
71 silly audit   '@types/jest': [ '25.2.1', '28.1.4' ],
..
71 silly audit   'identity-obj-proxy': [ '3.0.0' ],
71 silly audit   'jest-junit': [ '14.0.0' ],
..
71 silly audit   'ts-jest': [ '28.0.5' ]
```

I can get around this by explicitly installing each dependency, but that defeats the purpose of this package as the whole point of it is:

1. install specific versions of dependencies so the consumer doesn't have to figure out the correct versions to use
2. run a postinstall script to make a few tweaks to the project

I've used two versions of the latest NPM (v8), both 8.5.5 & 8.13.2 have the same behavior. At a loss as to why this would happen... no errors, warnings, or other stuff in the logs are giving clues as to why this is happening. Ideas?

Comment: It seems like the package was last published in July. If you want to use the changes you've made recently, you'll either have to publish the package, or if you just want to test it locally, use `npm link`.

Comment: The published version of my package is v1.4.1 (what you're referring to.

I'm testing a beta version (`@next` or `1.5.0-beta-XXXXX`) before I publish the package. I can see the changes I've made & testing, but as I explained in my OP, only some are being applied while others aren't.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, package resolution algorithms can be a bit unpredictable, and relying on this behavior can cause things to break when upgrading or changing your package manager. That being said, if you want to continue doing things this way but just have a little more control over the resolution, you can use `overrides` (npm) or `resolutions` (yarn) in `package.json`.

However, if I were maintaining this package, I'd prefer to explicitly list these dependencies as `peerDependencies` to ensure that the dependent package is resolving compatible versions. As of npm 7, npm will try to automatically install `peerDependencies` for you, but will error if there's a conflict (which you can fix with `overrides`).

Comment: I've tried moving them to `peerDependencies` as well... and using the `overrides` property for NPM v8... neither are having an effect.